# Adding a shadow to border in .net MAUI 8

Tags: android, border, maui, shadow, .net-8.0

I am trying to create cards with a shadow as shown in this [Mock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH9Vq.png) in .net maui 8.0

I am using a `Border` as the parent with a grid inside for the card's layout. However, when I add a shadow to the `Border`, the shadow only gets added on all elements inside the grid. Like in this image of [resulting view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNABc.png). The official documentation asks us to use `Border` instead of `Frame` and use `Shadow` instead of `HasShadow` but doesn't provide any examples.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="5*, 2*"
        Margin="10, 10, 10, 5" >

<Label Text="Your Chores"
            FontSize="Large"
            FontAttributes="Bold" />

<!--Add Button-->

<Border BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource DarkBackground}}" 
        Stroke="{StaticResource ButtonColor}"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 4"
        Grid.Column="1" >
  <Border.Shadow>
  <Shadow Offset="20,20"
         Radius="40"
         Opacity="0.8" />
  </Border.Shadow>

    <Grid 
        Padding="10, 8, 4, 8"
        ColumnDefinitions="20, *"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" >

        <Grid HeightRequest="20">
            <Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource ButtonColor}" />
            <Label Text="+"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource White}" />
        </Grid>

        <Label Text="Add"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource ButtonColor}" />



    </Grid>

</Border>
```

The project is only being run on android.

Is there a property to be assigned to ask the shadow to be avoided on child UI elements?

How do I get the border to have the shadow?

Comment: Based on the code you shared, I didn't get the result as you shared in the screenshot.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I created a simplified version of issue here: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/maui-borders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set property `BackgroundColor` for the `Border`(not `Transparent`).

Note that setting this `BackgroundColor` also sets the color of the stroke, thus making it invisible. In other words, if you need a shadow and border outline, setting the `BackgroundColor` will hide the outline. If a border outline is needed, this color needs to be manually set using something like `Stroke="Black"`.

```
<Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 6"   
        BackgroundColor="Pink">

    <Border.Shadow>
        <Shadow Brush="Gray"
                    Offset="20,20"
                    Radius="40"
                    Opacity="0.8"/>
    </Border.Shadow>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>

</Border>
```

**Note:**

I found if we don't set the `BackgroundColor` for the `Border`, the `BackgroundColor` of Border will be black. And if we set the `BackgroundColor="Transparent"` for the Border, the inner children will have shadows just as you mentioned, for this problem, you can create a new issue here: [bug-report](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=t%2Fbug&projects=&template=bug-report.yml).

And there is a known issue about this, you can check it here: [Shadow not displaying properly in Border](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13944) .

Comment: Thanks. I figured the background part too. I did go through the git repo in the issue you mentioned earlier. Didn't work with .net8 and seemed different from mine. 
However, does your code display the rounded border correctly?

Comment: Ok so hot reload doesn't work well with borders so it took a couple of tries but this code finally kindda works. I am marking it as the answer since it solves the specific layout I mentioned. However, it does have some issues

Answer (score -1):

`

```
.
.
.
       <Border.Shadow>
            <Shadow
                Brush="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource SampleLight},
                                        Dark={StaticResource SampleDark}}"
                Opacity=".5"
                Offset="15,15" />
        </Border.Shadow>
    </Border>
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).